# Getting a StackOverflowError from a Collection Class and its stored objects. Has anyone had a similar dilemma?

Tags: java, arraylist, stack-overflow

I'm completing a Command Design Pattern assignment, and I've run into a StackOverflowError.  I've looked up the < init > that comes with the error and it says it has to do with my constructor.

My professor and I have looked it over and we can't seem to find a problem.  Maybe an extra set of eyes might do the trick.

Compiled Program:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

```
at Command.AyyTacoMenu.addItem(AyyTacoMenu.java:39)
at Command.AyyTacoMenu.<init>(AyyTacoMenu.java:13)
at Command.AyyTacoItem.<init>(AyyTacoItem.java:8)
at Command.AyyTacoMenu.addItem(AyyTacoMenu.java:39)
at Command.AyyTacoMenu.<init>(AyyTacoMenu.java:13)
at Command.AyyTacoItem.<init>(AyyTacoItem.java:8)
at Command.AyyTacoMenu.addItem(AyyTacoMenu.java:39)...
```

Collection Class Code:

```
package Command;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;

public class AyyTacoMenu {
    private ArrayList<AyyTacoItem> atmenu;

    public AyyTacoMenu() {
        atmenu = new ArrayList<AyyTacoItem>();

        // System.out.println("Menu has been set to ArrayList of type AyyTacoItem");
        addItem("235", "Breakfast Enchillada", 10.00);
        addItem("236", "Burrito Bowl", 8.00);
        System.out.println("Items added");
    }

    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return atmenu.size();
    }

    public void addItem(String i, String n, double p) {
        AyyTacoItem x = new AyyTacoItem(i, n, p);
        atmenu.add(x);
    }

    public AyyTacoItem get(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return atmenu.get(i);
    }

}
```

Item Class Code:

```
package Command;

public class AyyTacoItem extends AyyTacoMenu {
    private String iD;
    private String name;
    private double price;

    protected AyyTacoItem(String i, String n, double p){
        System.out.println("Item being Added");
        iD = i;
        name = n;
        price = p;
        System.out.println("Item Added");
    }

    protected String getID() {
        return this.iD;
    }

    protected String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    protected double getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String x;
        x = ((this.iD) + " | " + (this.name) + " | $" + (this.price));
        return x;
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: how are you instantiating these classes? can we have a look at your `main` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class AyyTacoItem extends AyyTacoMenu
```

`AyyTacoItem` should not extends `AyyTacoMenu`. Otherwise the base class `AyyTacoMenu` must be constructed when constructing derived class `AyyTacoItem`, and `AyyTacoMenu`'s constructor attempted to construct another `AyyTacoItem`, which leads to infinite recursion.

Comment: totally agree that `AyyTacoItem` doesn't need to extend `AyyTacoMenu` because it doesn't seem to need to inherit any functionalities from its base class. But, he's not invoking the super class' constructor from the sub-class, I thought base classes' constructors must be invoke explicitly via the `super()` syntax

Comment: The default constuctor of base class is called automatically if there is no `super()` statement.

Comment: damn, you are right. I think I need to take a break from coding...+1